# DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Tags: mysql

I have a script which sends emails to customers who have items in shopping cart but who haven't completed the checkout. There is this WHERe statement:

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= c.date_add
```

I need to send the emails after 3 days (you put it in the cart today, you will get the reminder in 3 days). I don't want it to be less than 3 days or more than  days. But since the cron job is ran once day, it can't be exactly 3 days after putting in to cart.

What is the current WHERE saying? Would it be enough to change the 7 into 3 or should I have more modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DATEDIFF()

something as

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),c.date_add) > 3
```

Now since the cronjob rurns only once it may be few hours gap for users to get the email as you already mentioned, unless the cron is running every one minute.

As far as as using DATE_SUB() function is concern its

```
DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL expr unit)
```

So in your case you can have INTERVAL expr unit as 3.